# Sentry.io and using the withProfiler HOC for React performance...i think i'm missing something

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, sentry

So, I wanted to try out Sentry’s withProfiler component to see how it reports component performance. I followed the example at:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/#monitor-performance

The only difference is that the component is exported using redux compose(). So with Sentry, it looks something like this:

```
export default compose(
    withStuff,
    withMoreStuff,
    Sentry.withProfiler,
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(App);
```

I also tried wrapping a simple counter app as well. Just to see if it'd work without redux.

Then I visited my page, and watched the component render. I expected to see something in the projects performance dashboards. I see a timing for react.mount. But no react.render or react.update, even though the docs indicate it should be traced.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/components/profiler/

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spans data is tracked only when the transaction they belong to finishes, so if there is no ongoing transaction at the time your component updates, nothing about that will be sent to Sentry. When you "visit the page", Sentry's automatic performance tracking starts a `pageload` or a `navigation` transaction, and after that ends (which in your case I assume happens quite soon), no performance tracking will be done, unless you programmatically start another transaction (see [Custom Instrumentation for React | Sentry Documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/performance/instrumentation/custom-instrumentation/)).